# SELECT INTO SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a stored procedure, and I am trying to select values into variables.  I know this syntax works:

```
SELECT @variable = column_name from table_name where _____
```

However, this looks different from statements I've used in Oracle.  Is there another way to SELECT INTO variables?

Comment: It will be different - different DBMS have different dialects of the SQL. What's the problem with the above syntax?

Comment: There's no problem with the above syntax.  I just liked the syntax used with Oracle:
SELECT columnname from tablename into variable where ____.

Comment: I probably have the most experience coding with Oracle, but my first internship is with SQL Server.  Quite a pickle!

Comment: Note that in SQL Server, `'' IS NULL` is false--empty strings are not NULL!
And that `'abc ' = 'abc'` is true!
And that `Length('abc ') = 3`!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like the following:

```
set @variable = (select column_name from table_name where _____)
```

Answer (score -1):

Nope.  That's how you do it for stored procs in MS SQL

Comment: While technically this is the correct answer, I think this should have been left as a comment.

Comment: I'm still somewhat new here and don't fully understand the etiquette for when to use answers and when to use comments.  I thought comments were for clarifying and answers were for when you actually had an answer.  Is that not the case?

Comment: It is the case and I dont want to dissuade you from answering.  Like i said, it is correct.  However as an answer there is not a lot of value to it.  It's a screwy question anyway tho.

Comment: So, I can only use the above syntax in stored procs?  What should I use elsewhere?

Comment: @paqogomez That's not entirely true, the version shown in Jesan's answer is also valid. And to user3109653, no, it doesn't mean that it's valid **only** in stored procedures, both are valid syntax everywhere in SQL Server

Comment: @Lamak I'm hard pressed to believe that Jeasan's answer would result in a query plan much different from OP's, but I take your point.  _My_ point was that this should have been a comment.